# Printing Output in PyQGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

In developing a PyQGIS plugin, I would like to be able to print out variable values to ensure that my program has the desired functionality. I am aware that I can print messages with something like `QgsMessageLog.logMessage("hello")`, but this does not work for variable values.

Comment: Print directly to Python Console.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the native Python print e.g `print(your_variable)`